# firebase-queue initialization failing

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-queue

My Firebase Queue initialization is failing with the error below. I am using Firebase 3.

```
Task was malformed
```

Stack trace

```
"Error: Task was malformed\n    at Object.update
(/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase-queue/dist/lib/queue_worker.js:446:27)\n
at ei
(/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:217:395)\n
at U.h.transaction
(/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:232:466)\n
at
/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase-queue/dist/lib/queue_worker.js:439:30\n
at c
(/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:153:58)\n
at
/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:144:614\n
at Qb
(/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:43:165)\n
at sc
(/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:31:216)\n
at rc
(/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:30:1104)\n
at yg
(/Users/kanishkanagaraj/JeetLab/BetMe/firebase-queue/node_modules/firebase/database-node.js:215:313)"
```

My code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('queue');
    var queue = new Queue(ref, function(data, progress, resolve, reject) {

      console.log(data);


       // Do some work
      progress(50);

      // Finish the task asynchronously
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are trying to add a task that is only a string, you need to add an object, it should be something like this:

```
{
  "queue": {
    "tasks": {
      "someKey": {
        "foo": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```